# How to get unix timestamp in nanoseconds with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using `moment` and I have a datetime like `2020-11-04 21:01:54.434` in a moment object. I would like to obtain the unix timestamp in nanoseconds. I'm trying things like `moment.valueOf()` but they don't seem to be working up to nanosecond precision. Given that the moment object has information about the nanoseconds, is there anyway I can extract it as the number of seconds since unix epoch?

Comment: your title wants nanoseconds, your last question wants seconds ... and, since, regardless of library, javascript dates are in milliseconds, you'll want to multiply or divide my 1000 as required

Comment: @JaromandaX That would just add three more zeroes to the end of the number. It won't actually resolve the real nanoseconds.

Comment: @kovac that's true but also there isn't nanosecond information in the object anyway. I'm not sure why you think there is but there is nothing in the documentation about it.

Comment: I know ... because ... in javascript, you only HAVE microseconds - there are no nanoseconds in a javascript date, it does not have that level of accuracy

Comment: Not wanted in browser environment, due to security.

Comment: Maybe wait for [Temporal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal) if you want that sort of accuracy (though, how accurate it will be remains to be seen) - it has nanoseconds

Comment: @Estradiaz I am not sure how security comes into play with nanoseconds but it's definitely a problem with number representation. A timestamp in milliseconds is already 13 digits, the max safe intefer in JS is 16 digits long. So it's not actually possible to add *six* digits (nanosecond is 1/1000000) and ensure that the date represented is correct. [This site](https://www.convertunits.com/from/nanoseconds/to/milliseconds) is an example I entered the current timestamp `1604825460818` and it claimed that it's `1604825460818000100` in nanoseconds. Where did the 100 come from? Floating point math.

Comment: @VLAZ e.g. spectre ;)

Comment: @Estradiaz they planned for Spectre back when they first made the Date object in 1997 when the ES1 specs were released?

Comment: @VLAZ - FYI, in [temporal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal), the epoch nanoseconds is a BigInt

Comment: @JaromandaX that's what I'd expect from a proposal that comes after BigInt is a core part of the language. It would still take some time for it to come into the language, though. Hopefully it does.

Answer (score 0):

`Math.round(moment.getTime() * 1000)`

Because moment.getTime will return you time in milliseconds, so you have to convert it in nanoseconds

Comment: 1 sec =  1000 milli seconds;
1 sec = 1000,000 micro seconds;
1 sec = 1000,000,000 nano seconds